# Java JDBC Communications link failure after deploying online

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jdbc, sqlexception

I have created my first API using java httpServlet on netbeans. After days working I could finally connect it to this mySQL googleCloud database and get results locally. But once this API is published on google cloud using appengine, below error was thrown:

```
    Error sqlException:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
 Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0
 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

But the mySQL database is allowing access for all IPs, so what could be the problem? Below is my code:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        //out.println("Dear vistor, you are accessing my first project deployed on cloud. Thank you");

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = String.format("jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/DatabaseName?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "userName", "Password");            
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select test from tableTest;");
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            out.println("Error ClassNotFoundException:" + ex.toString());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            out.println("Error sqlException:" + ex.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            out.println("Exception:" + ex.toString());
        }
    }   
}
```

**Update:**

Based on  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896237/app-engine-java-servlet-does-not-connect-to-cloud-sql), I have discovered that when publishing online I should not use a password. So I have updated my code to use jdbc google drive in this way:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");

String url = String.format("jdbc:google:mysql://appId:instanceId/dbName?user=root");

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

But when I published online , same error was thrown...

**Update2:**

Could it be bcause my appId contains "-" like  "test-123"? But actually I am sending my url in this form:

url = "jdbc:google:mysql://test-123:myInstance/myDatabase?user=root&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";